# Add a additional column with value Yes or No if the max value group by matches

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table  lets say as below

| USER | Week | DAY | VERSION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | week 1 | SUNDAY | 5 |
| Second | Week 1 | MONDAY | 5 |
| FIrst | week 1 | SUNDAY | 3 |

Now I want to display all columns and rows and add additional column with Y  against each row when the row has max(version)  for that user and week  and if N if the version is not max for that user and week id . How could the sql query be written for this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be achieved with windowed functions:

```
SELECT *,
  CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY USER, WEEK ORDER BY VERSION DESC) = 1 
       THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
FROM tab;
```